# SSHTOOLS com.sshtools.common.ssh.SshException: No algorithms supported

Tags: sftp

I am trying to connect to SFTP server via SSH. I'm using SSHTOOLS maverick-synergy-3.0.10-all.jar.

I used their template at https://jadaptive.com/en/examples/java-ssh-client/transferring-files-by-sftp.

But I am getting:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sshtools.client.SshClientContext
at com.sshtools.client.SshClient.(SshClient.java:66)
...

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sshtools/common/logger/LoggerContext

I was trying to get the SSHTOOLS maverick-synergy-3.0.10 up and running, but its throwing exception.

Comment: To get an answer it would help if you could explain how you configured your classpath? Because the exception says your missing some classes

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  My classpath contained only maverick-synergy-client-3.1.0-all.jar.  Apparently it doesn't contain "all", I needed to download and add maverick-logging-3.1.0.jar, I grabbed it from

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sshtools/maverick-logging/3.1.0